# Line break before and after inline contenteditable element in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, frontend, contenteditable

I need to make inline element `contenteditable`. It works fine for Chrome/Firefox, but IE (11 at least) inserts line break before and after span if it's `contenteditable`.

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nokpy02g/1/

This is how it looks like in Chrome:

[image: chrome]

And this is IE:

[image]

Is there is any way to fix it?

**UPD:**

My IE version:

[image]

IE mode on my fiddle page:

[image]

Also, I am using Windows 7 Professional, 64bit

Comment: I can't see any reason to edit a child element of a paragraph, a bit pointless. You could try to `float: left;`: `p *[contenteditable] {float: left;}` is about all unless you *really* want to go crazy and script around the problem. I'd recommend rethinking editing *just* inline elements though.

Comment: @John Well, unfortunately, I already have a lot of code which is using this approach, so it's impossible to use another approach right now. We need this functionality to implement some kind of online editor, when one user can make marks for text ranges, and then another user can change text according to these marks (e. g. fix mistakes). I don't get it about your `float` solution, can you, please, make a fiddle with it?

Comment: Ah, looking at the Fiddle now. So IE11 64 Bit (standards mode w/Doctype) doesn't look like your screen shot; the spans render in the presumed/intuitive order in both Chrome 49 and IE 11. Confirm you're using IE 11 and that the page is being rendered in standards mode? Also do a diff on the style of the span and the DOM? I see no `br` elements and whitespace would only take effect in a `pre` element or an element with `white-space: pre;`.

Comment: @John I've updated my question with information about my environment. Yes, I am using IE11. Have you tried to resize your window to make span wrap? About BRs - I don't have any `br`s neither in my code, nor in my DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware: `contentEditable` is extremely buggy and inconsistent across all browsers and even versions. You are much, much better of using a JS WYSIWYG editor like CKEditor (which can edit inline). For example, some browsers will wrap the previous block of text when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a `<p>` or `<div>` or `<span>`, while others will enter `<br>`. Sometimes a `<br>` or two must be at the front or end. Two `<br>`s count as a single line...until it doesn't. **IE doesn't support `contentEditable` properly in table or inline elements.** Pasting inserts HTML rather than text. The problems go on and on, and will cause you endless frustration.

Comment: I guess you're right, it would be better to use CKEditor in my situation. However, we already have a lot of code using `contenteditable`, and, unfortunatelly, it's not an option to rewrite it right now. But, thank you, anyway.

Comment: OK fair enough, the only reason I say so is because I lost a lot of time (and hair) trying to get `contentEditable` to work, solving problems like yours, before I had realised WYSIWYG JS editors existed. I also don't actually think there is a solution without using JS, but I wish you well on your endeavour :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to achieve this.
https://jsfiddle.net/on695rz2/2/

```css
[contenteditable=true]:before {
  content: attr(before-content);
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px">
  <span before-content="4.5" contenteditable="true">Test this simple layout in IE11 and see the wonders of the internet!</span>
</div>
```

This keeps the first part ("4.5") non-editable and the rest editable.

[Span with contenteditable attribute won't behave as an inline element in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723297/span-with-contenteditable-attribute-wont-behave-as-an-inline-element-in-ie11/57728493#57728493)